# Пробелы в регулярных выражениях php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть код

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents("file.txt");
$zamena = array();
$zamena[0]="/^#EXTINF:0,/";
$zamena[1]="/\s\s$/";

echo preg_replace($zamena, "", $file);
?>
```

Файл file.txt

```
#EXTINF:0,Единица  
srs
#EXTINF:0,Двойка  
srt
#EXTINF:0,Тройка  
srt
#EXTINF:0,Четвёрка  
srt
```

регулярки не работают. Что делать?

Comment: вы бы полностью php-код привели, у вас может в другом месте ошибка

Comment: `/^(#EXTINF:0,).+(\s{2})$/`

Comment: andy.37 - не работает

Comment: `preg_replace(/^(#EXTINF:0,)(.+)(\s\s)$/, "$2", $file)` попробуйте. М.б. кавычки лишние во втором аргументе, я далек от ПХП.

Answer (score 3):

`preg_replace('/\s+$/m', '', $string)`

Если замена нужна только в строках с '#EXTINF:0...':

`preg_replace('/^(#EXTINF:0,\w+)\s+$/mu', '$1', $string)`

Comment: Работает. что значит m на конце?

Comment: @Vlad, см. [доки по модификаторам](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php
m (PCRE_MULTILINE)